# s3fs with public read permission for new files

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3fs

I have mounted the S3 bucket on linux server using s3fs. Now, While creating new file either with apache and root access it's default permission is assigning as private. We are not able to browse it until set it public from console.

How can we mount the bucket to have default public read permission for all new files, However i have mentioned it while mounting the directory but it is not working.

Below is command i uses to mount the bucket.

```
$ echo "s3fs#my-bucket-name /mount_folder fuse use_cache=/tmp,allow_other,uid=apache,gid=apache 0 0" >> /etc/fstab

$ s3fs -o allow_other -o use_cache=/tmp -o passwd_file=/etc/passwd-s3fs -o default_acl='public-read' my-bucket-name mount_folder
```

Please let me know is there anything else i will need to do or i am doing anything wrong.

EDITED:

I have notice that after rebooting the server it stop assigning the public read permission to new files, but it was working before rebooting the server.

Thank You

Comment: $umask output is 0022